# How to simulate a situation when non-empty Transaction Log file will be added to the SQL Server Full Database backup file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created a test database "StoredData" with a single table:

```
CREATE DATABASE StoredData 
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'StoredData', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\StoredData.mdf')
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'StoredData_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\StoredData_log.ldf')
GO

ALTER DATABASE [StoredData] SET RECOVERY FULL

GO

USE StoredData
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Users
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Then I inserted 3 records into that table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Users (Id, Name)
VALUES (1, 'John'),
       (2, 'Giovanni'),
       (3, 'Anna')
```

After that I run this query to have some active transactions:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0;

WHILE @i < 1000
BEGIN

    IF(@i%10 = 0) BEGIN TRAN

    INSERT INTO dbo.Users
    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.Users

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';  

    IF(@i%10 = 9) COMMIT

    SET @i = @i+1
END
```

During the last query execution I'm trying to do full database backup:

```
BACKUP DATABASE StoredData 
TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\StoredData_FullRecovery_Uncompressed.bak' 
WITH FORMAT, NO_COMPRESSION
```

Then I'm looking into the backup file content:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\StoredData_FullRecovery_Uncompressed.bak'
```

And getting zero log file inside backup:

```
LogicalName:       StoredData_log 
BackupSizeInBytes: 0
```

Comment: Post your query into https://dba.stackexchange.com/ blog

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong column for size of your files inside the backup file. you should look at the `SIZE` column, instead of `BackupSizeInBytes`. `BackupSizeInBytes` will tell you the size of your backup file it self(uncompressed size).

lets take a look at this picture:

[image]

This piece of information tells us that if we want to restore the `StoredData_FullRecovery_Uncompressed.bak` file, we will end up with 2 files. `StoredData` which will need about 8 MB space and the other `StoredData_log` which will need again 8 MB space.

**lets clarify with an example:**

suppose that I have created a database like below:

```
CREATE DATABASE [TestBackUp]
ON  PRIMARY 
 ( NAME = N'TestBackUp', FILENAME = N'<path>\TestBackUp.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
LOG ON 
 ( NAME = N'TestBackUp_log', FILENAME = N'<path>\TestBackUp_log.ldf' , SIZE = 81920KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
```

I have added a mdf file with 8MB initial size and a ldf file with 80MB initial size.

Then I perform a full backup from database:

```
BACKUP DATABASE TestBackUp
TO  DISK = N'<path>\TestBackUp.bak' 
WITH FORMAT, NO_COMPRESSION
```

now lets see this file size on disk:

[image]

It has about 2.67MB size on disk. Now lets run the `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` command:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM DISK = N'<path>\TestBackUp.bak'
```

and lets see the output:

[image]

As we can see, our backup file has 2555904  bytes size on disk(`BackupSizeInBytes`) and if we restore this backup file we will end up with two files, one will have 8MB size and the other will have 80MB size on disk after restoring the database(`Size`)

Now lets create a table and populate some data inside it, and analyze the whole process again:

```
USE TestBackUp
GO
CREATE TABLE t(col1 NCHAR(2000), col2 NCHAR(2000))
GO

INSERT INTO t VALUES('a', 'b')
GO 10000
```

lets see the RESTORE FILELISTONLY command's output again:

[image]

The output tells us that we have a backup file which has about 84MB size on disk. After restoring we will end up with two files, one mdf file with 142606336 bytes size on disk and one ldf file with 150994944 bytes size on disk. below you can see the files information and size on disk too. you can see that size of these files are same as the value of `size` column in `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` command.

[image]

Read more at: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/02/23/how-to-forecast-the-size-of-restore-of-backup-in-sql-server-interview-question-of-the-week-265/